# CakePHP 1.3 -> 2.0 Migration issue - URL Parameters

Tags: get, parameters, cakephp-2.0

In cakePHP 1.3 , when I try to get the variables GET sent on the url, I can use this :

```
$this->params['url'];
```

Example: `url = www.mySite.com/messages/get/?var1=1&var2=2`

the result of `$this->params['url'];` is :

```
Array => ( [url] => Array
    (
    [url] => messages/get
    [var1] => 1
    [var2] => 2
    )
)
```

But when I try to get those params from the same URL using cakePHP2.0, the result is in json format:

```
{"params":{"controller":"messages","named":[],"pass":[],"action":"index","plugin":null}}
```

There is no index 'url' in the array, so do you have any idea how to get those variables sent on the url that I posted using the attribute $params or something else?

**EDIT :**

i have tried this from the cookbook cakePHP2.0 :

```
<?php
// url is /posts/index?page=1&sort=title
$this->request->query['page'];

// You can also access it via array access
$this->request['url']['page'];
```

But i got the same Error :

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: page [APP\Controller\MessagesController.php, line 23]

Notice (8): Undefined index: page [APP\Controller\MessagesController.php, line 24]
```

Any ideas ??? how can i get the Variables sent on an url like this :

```
/posts/index?page=1&sort=title
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a new Request object in 2.0 that handles the query string among other things:

```
<?php
// url is /posts/index?page=1&sort=title
$this->request->query['page'];

// You can also access it via array access
$this->request['url']['page'];
```

From the [2.0 Request object docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/request-response.html?highlight=params#accessing-querystring-parameters).

Comment: thanks for your reply, i will try this and tell you  back if it works

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a bug.

It only works if the URL is `/posts/index?&page=1&sort=title` (with an extract `&` after `?`)